# strtok_r is returning incorrect data after tokenizing

Tags: c++, c, c-strings, strtok

Below is the code where I am trying to use strtok_r() to tokenize my string to fetch the first token i.e. 38 in this case.

If you observe the output somehow my token is incorrectly fetched (refer output :38 is fetched as 8)
This is an intermittent issue which doesn't occur everytime. I am unable to find any solution for this.

P.S. Ignore the logger function I used to print output, it's just something similar to printf()

```
char cDelimeter = ',';
char *pRecordString = NULL;
char *pRemainString = NULL;
char szMsgBuff[MAX_BUFFER];

/*some code*/

LOG2(INF,"#ONLINEREQ : <%s>", szMsgBuff);
LOG3(INF,"#ONLINEREQ Before tokenizing: pRecordString<%s> pRemainString<%s>", pRecordString,pRemainString);
pRecordString = strtok_r(szMsgBuff,&cDelimeter,&pRemainString);
LOG3(INF,"#ONLINEREQ After tokenizing: pRecordString<%s> pRemainString<%s>", pRecordString,pRemainString);
```

Output

```
#ONLINEREQ : <38,CM|Member Name|Total ED|Net Buy Premium|Init Margin|ELMMargin|PreExpMargin|AdhocMargin|DeliveryMargin|UNDirectionalMRGN|CONMRGN|Crystallised MTM|Fwd Init Margin|Fwd Mntnce Margin|Total Utilization|Free Capital|MTM P/L|%ofEffectiveloss,^M
>
#ONLINEREQ Before tokenizing: pRecordString<(null)> pRemainString<(null)>
#ONLINEREQ After tokenizing: pRecordString<8> pRemainString<CM|Member Name|Total ED|Net Buy Premium|Init Margin|ELMMargin|PreExpMargin|AdhocMargin|DeliveryMargin|UNDirectionalMRGN|CONMRGN|Crystallised MTM|Fwd Init Margin|Fwd Mntnce Margin|Total Utilization|Free Capital|MTM P/L|%ofEffectiveloss,^M
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the man page `strtok_r` has a `const char *` delimeter. I would guess that you're screwing up the operation by pointing to a randomly terminated string, i.e.`&cDelimeter`.

Try ...

```
const char *cDelimeter = ",";

...

pRecordString = strtok_r(szMsgBuff,cDelimeter,&pRemainString);
```